# When is "race" worthwhile in Perl 6?

Tags: concurrency, raku

[`race`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/race) divides operations on an iterable automatically into threads. For instance,

```perl6
(Bool.roll xx 2000).race.sum
```

would automatically divide the sum of the 2000-long array into 4 threads. However, [benchmarks show](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/50fbba42544f1472543aa997f91a4c1d) that this is much slower than if `race` were not employed. This happens [even if you make the array bigger](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/57fd99f76f59e1af97db01544a7b8f2c). 
This happens even as the [non-autothreaded version gets faster and faster with each version](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/81191278502dc1a352a254b647e28308). ([Auto-threading also gets faster](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/28dc7965c035258f14585ec8c9cc5a21), but is still twice as slow as not using it.)

So the question is: what is the minimum size of the atomic operation that is worthwhile to use? Is the overhead added to the sequential operation fixed or can it be decreased somehow?

**Update**: in fact, [performance of `hyper` (similar to race, but with guaranteed ordered results) seems to be getting worse with time](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/e09069f58f4712bf2c4b32b3bbf8401b), at least for small sizes which are nonetheless integer multiples of the default batch size (64). Same [happens with `race`](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/319587af276dddbeec2af7cefc2c5aa2)

Comment: “Atomic operation” has a very specific meaning in programming. It doesn’t mean “fewest operations/expressions/statements”

Comment: Hi jj. FYI: 1) "`(Bool.roll xx 2000).race.sum` would automatically divide the sum of the 2000-long array into 4 threads." It **potentially** would. It's up to the compiler whether it actually would. 2) "auto-threading" has [a specific meaning in the context of P6](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Autothreading). It doesn't mean automatically run on threads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer: `.sum` isn't smart enough to calculate sums in batches.

So what you're effectively doing in this benchmark, is to set up a `HyperSeq` / `RaceSeq` but then not doing any parallel processing:

```
dd (Bool.roll xx 2000).race;
# RaceSeq.new(configuration => HyperConfiguration.new(batch => 64, degree => 4))
```

So you've been measuring `.hyper` / `.race` overhead.  You see, at the moment, only `.map` and `.grep` have been implemented on `HyperSeq` / `RaceSeq`.  If you give *that* something to do, like:

```
# find the 1000th prime number in a single thread
$ time perl6 -e 'say (^Inf).grep( *.is-prime ).skip(999).head'
real    0m1.731s
user    0m1.780s
sys     0m0.043s

# find the 1000th prime number concurrently
$ time perl6 -e 'say (^Inf).hyper.grep( *.is-prime ).skip(999).head'
real    0m0.809s
user    0m2.048s
sys     0m0.060s
```

As you can see, in this (small) example, the concurrent version is more than 2x as fast as the non-concurrent one.  But uses more CPU.

Since `.hyper` and `.race` got to work correctly, performance has slightly improved, as you can see [in this graph](https://gist.github.com/Whateverable/ee98308dcca3561d46bff8128bc4de20).

Other functions, such as `.sum` could be implemented for `.hyper` / `.race`.  However, I would hold off on that at the moment, as we will need a small refactor of the way we do `.hyper` and `.race`: at the moment, a batch can not communicate back to the "supervisor" how fast it has finished its job.  The supervisor needs that information if we want to allow it to adjust e.g. batch-size, if it finds out that the default batch-size is too small and we have too much overhead.

Comment: So it would work better with some sensible function? Would that be the case for any similar function such as `.min`?

Comment: @jjmerelo `sum` is a sensible function to use, ignoring that it has to do all of it's work before it returns it's one result, so there'll never be any ordinary useful visible functioning difference between `.hyper` and `.race`. (The same will be true of `.min`.) lizmat's point is that "only `.map` and `.grep` have been implemented on `HyperSeq` / `RaceSeq`" and that "Other functions, such as `.sum` could be implemented for `.hyper` / `.race`. However, I would hold off on that at the moment".